# App architecture and portable modules - organisation

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework2

Recently, I have decided to the my project with ZF2, instead of Symfony. Now, I am stuck with architectural problem with modules.

Let's say we have an app, that allows us to:

- add new rooms
- add new people and assign them to rooms
- add new invoices and choose people that have to pay for them

My first thought was to create one module "House" with rooms and people and another one with invoices.

But, what if I have some sql joins in invoices modules that need data from the "House" ? This condition really makes them depend on each other so they are no longer portable. So, they should be stored in one module...

I think that creating another module as a "dashboard" that will connect invoices and house data together would be a solution to keep them portable but it will make quite simple app too fragmented.

Am I missing something? It's more about subjective project organisation (then I am right) or about portability (then I should group everything in one module).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### When to Create a New Module

In ZF2, a module is an autonomous and reusable unit of your application. By default your application has the single Application module. And it is normal to put your models, views and controllers in this module.

You might need to create a new module when the following are true:

- If the functionality you are implementing is autonomous (has no or few dependencies on other modules of your application. For example, the user management functionality in theory can be separated in another module, because it does not depend on the rest of the application, but the application depends on it.
- If a module can be separated from your application and concurrently used in another project. For example the user management module can be reused in another project without changes (only its configuration may require changes).

In any case, real life is complex, and you should be guided by the intuition when it seems that it is necessary to create a new module. If you think the separating a functionality in a module gives you some significant benefits, then create the module.

At the same time, you should not be abused by creating a huge number of almost empty modules, it is better to combine related functionality in a single module.

#### Module Dependencies

It is OK, if one module depends on another one. In this case, you will just have to install both modules, and everything will work.

For example, when you install `DoctrineORMModule` with Composer, this module depends on `DoctrineModule`, which is automatically installed to resolve dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I was offline for a month, but you help me a lot! Now things are much more clearer :)